# How do I display a message on the screen

Tags: lxde

Ok, I know it sounds like a dumb question but how do I show a black screen with custom text on it from LXDE desktop. I have looked on the internet for a while all I could find was this:

export IP=`ip addr show eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet )(\d+\.){3}\d+'`
wish "<<" END &
pack [label .ip -text "$IP" -font "Helvetica 72" -fg grey -bg black]
END

However I want this to be fullscreen.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I see is you have two options.
1. Write a shell script that would display the text.
2. Write a GUI(Graphical User Interface) using a language that you like.(E.g Python)

Comment: Can you be a little more specific?

Comment: Ok. The progress you want is to make a black full screen with custom text appear on the desktop.<br>

Comment: Yeah, I don't know how to write a shell script that displays text on the screen, and I don't know how to write a gui.

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-write-output-to-terminal/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_gui_programming.htm
I started from those pages. Hope it will help you,too.

Answer (score 2):

Do you mean displaying a notifying message on Screen, 
If this is what you want you can use "notify-send"

$notify-send "Message to be displayed"

create one script :
1. leafpad display_Ip.sh

2. Write following lines :

   `#!/bin/bash
   IP=ip addr show eth0 | grep -oP '(?<=inet )(\d+\.){3}\d+'
   notify-send "$IP"`
3. Save it.
4. Make it executable by:
   chmod 777 display_Ip.sh
5. ./display_Ip.sh

It will show your IP on the Screen as Notification.

PS: If notify-send is not installed, install it using apt-get install.

Comment: I tried "sudo apt-get install notify-send" and it couldn't be found. Do I need to add a repo?

Comment: I Guess, o need of adding repo you can do `apt-get update; apt-get upgrade; apt-get install libnotify-bin` 
This will install notify-send command in your pi

Comment: Are you sure this works on the raspberry pi? I don't see the notification after I run: notify-send "Hello, World"

Comment: Yes it will work. Have you started X server using startx